# Apache Setup Multiple Project On Test Server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos, centos7

I'm using CentOS 7 and Apache on my Virtualbox.

This VM has its own IP address (XXX.XX.XX.XX).

Having this setting below, I can access my project on the browser by typing `http://XXX.XX.XX.XX`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>       
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/       

  <Directory /var/www/html/project_name/> 
    AllowOverride All 
  </Directory> 

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_name-error_log 
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_name-common_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is I have another web app project that will run on this machine.

Can I configure wherein the two projects will be accessible using different port numbers like below?

```
http://192.168.10.1:8001
http://192.168.10.1:8002
```

**SOLUTION:**

Here's how I managed it to make it work:

```
Listen 8001
Listen 8002 

<VirtualHost *:8001> 
ServerName ipaddress:8001 

<VirtualHost *:8002> 
ServerName ipaddress:8002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name1/public/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name1/public/
</VirtualHost>
```

Try this. Inside config you can set multiple domain with different directory on same port 80

Second option running like http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/project1 and http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/project2

set up in .htaccess inside project folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/mm.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/mm.*$
    RewriteRule ^/mm/(.*)$ public/mm/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: thank you but this is just a developer server and i dont have a domain name

Comment: you can set like xx.xx.xx.xx/project_name and xx.xx.xx.xx/project_name2

Comment: http://192.168.10.1:8001
http://192.168.10.1:8002 this way also you can do

Comment: i tried what you said but if i enter `http://ipaddress/project1` it's just a directory browsing, but if i enter `http://ipaddress/project1/public` it will work. how can i do `http://ipaddress/project1` only?

Comment: php artisan serve --port=8001 this for project and run using 192.168.10.1:8001 and php artisan serve --port=8002 this for project2 and run using 192.168.10.1:8002

Comment: this is apache on centos?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202777/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-kapitan).

Comment: putting `Listen 81` and `Listen 82` then `<VirtualHost *:81> ServerName ipaddress:81` and `<VirtualHost *:82> ServerName ipaddress:82` on the configuration file works. but you need to reboot the server, simply restarting the apache service will not work.