# Deploy Multiple Sites on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp, virtualhost, amazon-route53

I am new to AWS and my requirement is described below. Hope your advice will help to resolve my issue.
I have developed 2 PHP projects. both based on YII Framework.

I have created AWS EC2 enstance and have set up an elastic IP address too. and I installed the XAMPP server on the instance that I created. so my projects are working as follows /project1 and /project2

I need to point these 2 projects to separate subdomains. like,
project1 => project1.mydomainname.com
project2 => project2.mydomainname.com

can somebody give me a hint to accomplished this, Please?

Comment: [VirtualHost Examples - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968084/apache-setup-multiple-project-on-test-server/58968692#58968692 see this it will help you. @VimukthiJayasinghe

Comment: thanks, both of you. managed to resolve that with your help.